# Find $P[X > s + t | X > t]$ with $f(x) =λe^{−λx}\mathbb{1}_{[0,∞)}(x)$

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

I wnated to know if I have solved this problem right or if I have done some errors.

Can someone help me?

Let $X$ be an exponentially distributed random variable, i.e. for the parameter $λ > 0$ the density is given by $f(x) =λe^{−λx}\mathbb{1}_{[0,∞)}(x)$. For $t > 0$ determine the conditional distribution $P[X > s + t | X > t]$, $s ≥ 0$.

So I calculated as follows:

$P[X > s + t | X > t]=\frac{P[X > s + t, X > t]}{P[X >t]}=\frac{P[X > s + t]}{P[X >t]}\\
=\frac{1-P[X \leq s + t]}{1-P[X \leq t]}=\frac{1-(1-e^{−λ(s+t)})}{1-(1-e^{−λ(t)})}\\
=\frac{e^{−λ(s+t)}}{e^{−λt}}=e^{-λs}$

Comment: That's correct, assuming $t \geq 0$ as well.